# Use HTML atribute as a variable name on jQuery

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div data-section="html" class="cono-html">                        
<div data-section="css" class="cono-css">                
<div data-section="jquery" class="cono-jquery">
```

jQuery:

```
var html="<div class='radial-info'>El lenguaje histórico</div>";
var css="<div class='radial-info'>Las hojas de estilo CSS ya no sólo dan aspecto estático</div>";
var jquery="<div class='radial-info'>Una interminable lista de recursos de Javascript</div>";
```

I would like to make an .append with jQuery, inserting the content stored on the variable with the same name as the attribute "data-section" on the item clicked, avoiding to create an if statement.

When I try things like:

```
obj.append(obj.attr('data-section'));
```

or

```
section=obj.attr('data-section');
obj.append(section);
```

It just appends the name of the attribute, and not the content stored on the variable with the same name. What procedure do you use for this?

Comment: `$(obj).append($(obj).data('section'));` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support this kind of "dynamic" variables, you can't just insert a string somewhere and expect it to reference a variable.

If you create an object, you can use bracket notation like this :

```
var stuff = {
    html   : "<div class='radial-info'>El lenguaje histórico</div>",
    css    : "<div class='radial-info'>Las hojas de estilo CSS ya no sólo dan aspecto estático</div>",
    jquery : "<div class='radial-info'>Una interminable lista de recursos de Javascript</div>"
};

obj.append( stuff[obj.attr('data-section')] );
```

You could also do something like this to get globally defined variables

```
window[obj.attr('data-section')]
```

depending on the the scope you're in, but you shouldn't, use an object instead.

Comment: Very grateful. I'll tick in 7 minutes.